# mongodb: $sort and $limit behaves weird with undefined

Tags: mongodb

I'm on latest version (2.6.3 I believe) of mongodb.

I have the following aggregate:

```
{
   "$project": {
        "summary": 1,  
        "priority": 1,
        "sortDate": {
           "$ifNull": [
              "$targetDate",
              "$deadlineDate"
           ]
        }
   }
},
{
  "$sort": {
      "priority": -1,
      "sortDate": 1
   }
}
```

Some objects in the collection have both `targetDate` and `deadlineDate` undefined.

Now here is the weird thing. If I run this, I get all eleven back:

1. The one with priority 3
2. One with priority 2 and no sortDate
3. Another one with priority 2 and no sortDate
4. The ones with priority 2 and sortDate (in correct order)
5. ... etc priority 1

I understand why undefined is before the valued ones, even if I don't like it. But, if I add

> { "$limit": 2 }

to the aggregation pipeline, I'd expect to get back *1 and 2* from the above list. **I get back 1 and 3 instead**!!!! How?

This causes further weirdness down the line; if I use skip/limit to page, some items will appear on multiple pages, causing the clientside object tracker to freak out and crash, but I definitely nailed this sorting anomaly as the root cause of all those problems.

Comment: `limit` only limits the number of documents searched, not the number of documents returned.

Comment: can you show us an the example docs you throw into the pipeline from your collection so we can get an idea their values first hand?

Comment: @ma08: Is there any way to do sort+limit then? (for paging, with or without aggregate)

Comment: $limit will limit the number of documents returned when not used with a $match

Comment: @Sammaye Are you sure? Check [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

Comment: @ma08 it does say "Restricts the number of documents that pass through the $limit in the pipeline." unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: This aggregate will occasionally have $match too, ideally the solution should work regardless

Comment: @Sammaye Got it. As we are not using any $match, limit will be the number of documents returned. My bad.

Comment: Form what I understand is that $limit should work the way you want after your first projection, the limit thing is to stop excessive memory from being used at the head of the pipeline, aka reading from the collection itself

Comment: @Sammaye: So, that just means limit works as I understand it. So why the weird result?

Comment: But as you are using $sort and $limit in combination, the combination gives you undesired results. The sort might be limited to 2 documents only thus you are not getting the desired result. I think it is limiting and then sorting instead of the other way round.

Comment: Hmm that's sounds like a bug in that case, if limit causes only 2 documents to be sorted even when put after the sort. Gonna need to test

Comment: What you need is to slice after sorting. But [there is no slice operator in aggregation framework](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074). :(. This has bugged me a lot when using aggregation.

Comment: wait the return of your query is correct, you are srting by priority, it should return 3 first and then one 2nd with null date. Most likely you get 1 and 3 because of the way the documents are gong in, basically bad luck mate

Comment: Adding _id : 1 as third sort condition fixed it, so I'm betting it has something to do with sortDate being undefined.

Comment: Yeah it is pot luck as I just realised when I looked again or rather $natural luick

Comment: Actually I am wrong, my understanding does not explain why without limit you get 1,2,3 and with you get 1,3. I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clear up a couple of misunderstandings that I feel might be lurking based on the comments:

1. `$limit` is a pipeline stage that always cuts down the number of documents in the pipeline to at most the specified number. There's nothing tricky about it affecting what is "searched" versus "returned". It's just a pipeline stage that transforms one set of documents into another set by getting rid of all the ones > n in the order the documents are presented to it, when the limit parameter is `n`. Note that the order might not be very meaningful. We'll talk about the tricky part in a second :D
2. The result returned by the aggregation query with `$limit` isn't wrong; it's just different. Both have the same sort key, so you really can't complain if the two pipelines returned 123 and 132, respectively, and then limit 2 gives you 12 and 13, respectively. I understand how, if you went on to use `$match`, etc. later on on other fields, the results could be surprising, but you can't say that the output is wrong.

As for an explanation of why we see 13 instead of 12, my guess is that it has to do with [`$sort`+`$limit` coalescence](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#agg-sort-limit-coalescence). The limit affects how the sort occurs, effectively making it quit earlier. My guess is that, since it quits earlier, it never considers 2, which, when it is considered without a `$limit`, is sorted before 3 (they have the same sort key, so it doesn't matter where it's put).

If you post example documents and a complete aggregation pipeline, perhaps there's more that could be said to help you, but this is my guess based on what I see.

Comment: Some would ague that since the difference exists between using limit and no limit that it is wrong

Comment: That's a reasonable argument, but I think it's surprising behavior that leads to wrong results when the computation of the results is based on (reasonable but wrong) assumptions, and then people blame the server for doing something that's right according to strict interpretations of what they told it to do, but is not what they (entirely reasonably) expected.